# How to parse JSDoc in multiple .js files

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gulp, jsdoc

I have many javascript files. I need to extract jsdoc using some jsdoc parser ([gulp-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jsdoc), [jsdoc-parse](https://github.com/75lb/jsdoc-parse), or another).

Using the following approach I get one huge `dist/documentation.json` file, which contains JSON for all my scripts.

```
var jsdoc = require("gulp-jsdoc");    
gulp.src("mysrc/*/*.js")
    .pipe(jsdoc.parser({}, "documentation.json"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

But I need as many small separated `.json` files as many `.js` files I have.

Second way. Using `jsdoc-parse` I get into another trouble. I don't know how to properly write result to files instead of `process.stdout`.

```
var parse = require("jsdoc-parse");
var tap = require('gulp-tap');
gulp.src("mysrc/*/*.js")
     .pipe(tap(function(file) {
          parse(file.path).pipe(process.stdout); // how to write it to file?
     });
```

Help me to finish this Gulp task, please.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with `gulp-jsdoc`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jsdoc = require("gulp-jsdoc");   
var tap = require('gulp-tap'); 

gulp.task('jsdoc', function() {
  gulp.src("mysrc/*/*.js")
    .pipe(tap(function (file) {
      gulp.src(file.path)
        .pipe(jsdoc.parser({}, file.relative))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
    }));
});
```

But it still would be nice if somebody help me to rewrite task using `jsdoc-parse`. `jsdoc-parse` produces better JSON.